# Power bi Multiple slicers effecting one table

Tags: powerbi

I was wondering if its possible and whats the best way to have two slicers based on date, affecting two separate columns in a single table in Power BI. A bit like the attached image. I'd like more flexibility in the comparison dates week/month/3month/year etc...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One good approach is to build [time intelligence as bridge tables](https://www.kasperonbi.com/time-intelligence-solved-with-modelling-and-crossfilter-instead-of-dax-measures/) so it applies to all measures.

Since your date periods (Current week and Previous week) are not overlapping, a different approach is to create a new column in your Date dimension called Relative Week with values Current week, Previous week, and Other.

With both of these approaches use a matrix visual in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create measure with you lastWeek, lastMonth, LastQuarter, Lastyear... then you can create a table with LW, LM, LQ, LY and use as a filter. Then you just need to have another measure similar to:

`=SWITCH('Date Selection'[Selected Date],
    "Lw", [lastWeek],
    "LM", [lastMonth],
    ... )`